# Python UpSetPlot returning error: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'levels'

Tags: python, matplotlib, upsetplot

I have been trying to get an [UpSetPlot](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to work and have not been having much luck.

My code is quite simple, I have already shaped the data in a CSV. Below is what I have been trying to run.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from upsetplot import UpSet
upset = pd.read_csv ("upset.csv")
plot(upset)
pyplot.show()
```

The data looks like this:

| cat0 | cat1 | cat2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | 56 |
| FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | 283 |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | 1279 |
| FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | 5882 |

I based my data off the example used in the UpSetPlot so it *should* work - Not quite sure where I have gone wrong.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a step here. After reading the data, you need to convert it to a Upset-compatible format. You can read more about it [here](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats.html#Convert-Data-to-UpSet-compatible-format).

Based on the steps mentioned, you can to use `from_memberships()` to convert it before plotting. This will convert the data to a series with multiple indices which is required. Updated code below. I saved your data in excel instead of csv, but should result in same plot.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from upsetplot import UpSet, plot, from_memberships
upsetraw = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx", 'Sheet17')
upset = from_memberships(upsetraw)
plot(upset)
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! I did actually come across from_memberships but ended up disregarding as some of the homepage examples don't seem to use it. Works prefect now, cheers!

Comment: Hello, the graph is incorrect; the header string "cat0 cat1 cat2" has been divided into characters. Do you know how to correct it? @Redox